# GPO policy to give write permissions to java applications in C drive

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, group-policy, java

I wish to run the following instruction in a Windows cmd: java -jar app.jar. App.jar is an application in charge of creating a file in the Temp folder of the Windows user folder but it fails because it does not have write permissions. The windows user is given full control on C drive. Then the command is executed but the same message keeps. Is there a GPO policy in Windows Server that allows java applications to create and modify files on C drive?

Comment: how is the program executed? Maybe it is just not execuded in the users context, but with another account that does not have the permissions?

Comment: The user can create a text file in Temp folder by File Explorer and modify it manually. But the user opens a cmd and executes java -jar app.jar. App.jar is in charge of creating the text file in Temp folder but it fails because of a lack of writing permissions. We didn't test with another account.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check with Java usergroup to see why it couldn't write file. OS-wise, all you need is to grant write permission against TEMP folder to the user who runs the application. You don't need to touch GPO
However if you granted permission but that permission is later gone by itself then there (could) be a GPO enforcing folder permissions

Comment: Keeping with the case. Let's suppose that file created is a digital certificate in pem or p12 format. The java app is also in charge to install the digital certificate in Windows Certificate Manager but it fails because of a lack of permission. Question: Is there any GPO to enable to java app installs digital certificates?

Comment: creating a file (regardless if it's text file or cert file) vs. install certificate are 2 totally different things. They require different permissions. May or may not be with GPO depending on if your admin has set up such GPO. When asking question, be specific, provide details. For example, it won't help others to help you if you simply said "failed". What failed? What did you try to do? How did you do it? What was the error message? Etc. These are asking question 101.

Comment: I mean the installation of digital certificate in Windows Certificate Manager (certmgr.msc) fails baucase a lack of permission. Writing permissions. The certificate is stored in C drive. Unfortunately, I can't replay the error to get the exact message . The idea of my second question is to know which gpo or permission to enable.